# What about the Apps that I bought on the App Store when I buy a new iPod?

Tags: ipod-touch

Will the App be synched when I connect my new iPod on my Mac ?
Do I have to do something special before selling my old iPod ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At the very least, make sure you sync your old one to your Mac before you sell it. When you sync, it should copy purchased items from your iPod to your Mac.

If you have time, back up your iPod: Connect it to iTunes, then right-click (or control-click) and select Back Up. You can then restore your new iPod from that backup. This will restore your mail accounts, sync settings and app data to the new iPod. It *will not* restore the correct locations of your apps or home screen folder contents.

Comment: i believe iOS does restore your icon locations now.  when i upgraded from 3GS to 4 everything was back in the same spot and all photos, texts, and notes were restored as well.

Comment: I did a restore yesterday, and it didn't restore my item locations, except for the built-in apps. It synced the correct apps and their data back to the device, but I had to manually rearrange them again.